# Is the latency for the sendinput / receiving raw input the same or almost the same for all programs?

Tags: winapi, benchmarking, timing, raw-input, sendinput

I'm using winapi `SendInput` with scancodes to simulate keyboard input to a game, and at the same time I want to measure the timing of the input being received, but unfortunately I've no access to that data from the game itself.

I know it uses listens to raw input, using the `RegisterRawInputDevices`, so I've my program take two measurements, timing right before calling `sendinput` and listing to the rawinput itself, the timing that my program received the input sent by `RegisterRawInputDevices`, by subtracting the two, I can have a rough estimation of the latency of the input stack.

Is my assumption correct, and the time at which I received the raw input, will probably be a better approximation to the time the game received it, that the time at which I called `sendInput`, and is there a better way of measuring that?

Comment: What's the specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: SendInput() is incapable of generating raw input, so safe to assume the latency is infinite.

Comment: @HansPassant `SendInput()` posts its events into the same input queue that hardware devices post their events to. Thus, the Raw Input API can pick up `SendInput()` events.

Comment: @HansPassant exactly what Remy Lebeau said, and I'm using scan codes in case that makes a difference